# Get last 5 weeks from data stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have inherited an app which stores its attendance dates in MySQL database. Dates as stored as periods for week starting Monday till Friday for each year.

The schema of the db is illustrated below:

```
PeriodYear | WeekNo |  WeekStartDate
2015       | 49     |  07-12-2015
2015       | 50     |  14-12-2015
2015       | 51     |  21-12-2015
2015       | 52     |  28-12-2015
2016       | 01     |  04-01-2016
2016       | 02     |  11-01-2016
```

I need to get last 4 weeks from MySQL. 
The problem is  if I do a select on  current year (i.e.2016) I get only 1 week as week 52 is in year 2015.

How can I get last 4 weeks (i.e week 49 - 2015, week 52 -2015, week 51 - 2015, week 50 - 2015)?

Comment: show the code what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLEHERE 
WHERE WeekStartDate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK) AND NOW()
```

Comment: Th interval period should be `week` not `weeks`

Comment: Thank you it worked great. I didn't realise that data type for PeriodWeekDate  was not datetime instead it was int(10).